# Fullcalendar V4 or V5, How to remove the slot label row in resourceTimeline type

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4, fullcalendar-5

I am upgrading fullcalendar-scheduler 1.9.4 to v5 beta2. 
I found that the behaviour of `slotLabelInterval` has been changed from v3 to v4.

My objective : I want to totally remove the slot label row. My setting in V1.9.4 is like below (It works) :

```
...    
weekNumbers: true,
views: {
            timelineThreeDays: {
              type: 'timeline',
              duration: { days: 3 },
              slotLabelInterval: '24:00:00'
            }
          },
...
```

[image]

But the setting "slotLabelInterval: '24:00:00'" don't do the same thing in `resourceTimeline` type with Fullcalendar-Scheduler 5 beta2 (same as v4)

```
...    
weekNumbers: true,
views: {
            timelineThreeDays: {
              type: 'resourceTimeline',
              duration: { days: 3 },
              slotLabelInterval: '24:00:00'
            }
          },
...
```

The screenshot for the above code :
[image]

What I have tried :

- set slotDuration to 24 at the same time than slotLabelInterval (It didn't works)
- set slotLabelFormat: { weekday: 'short', month: 'short' } (It didn't works, it always display slot time label )

Question: How to make the same effet like the first screenshot with V5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In v4 (or the v5 beta) you can set the same time period like this:

```
slotLabelInterval: { days: 1 },
```

Demo: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/abvqBrN